# create json object from csv file data coming as buffer in request in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, csv-parser

I'm processing `csv` file data coming from request to create json object using `multer`,`csv-parser`. but can't process from long time. please help and thanks.following is example of csv file processing.

```
const multer = require('multer');
const fs = require('fs')
const csv =  require('csv-parser')
const fileStorageEngine = multer.memoryStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, './csv');
  }
  ,
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  },
});
const upload = multer({storage:fileStorageEngine});
app.post('/uploadcsv',upload.single("upfile"),async(req,res)=>{
const file = req.file;
fs.createReadStream(`./csv/${file.originalname}`)
.pipe(csv())
.on("data",(data)=>console.log(data));
res.send("file uploaded")
})
```

here I'm using `fs` module that works for me but I  don't want to store data in file instead I want to process buffer data coming from `req.file.buffer` in chunk
I'm stuck here please help. because storing file and reading same  file getting process slow because csv file have thousands of data.

Comment: When you say "JSON object", please clarify if you mean a JS object or JSON (a string)?

Comment: If you don't want to store the uploaded file on the harddisk, why not remove all the code that does that? `memoryStorage()` has no options and returns a Buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to create a readable stream from the buffer instead of writing it to the file as follows:

```
const multer = require('multer');
const { Readable } = require('stream');
const fs = require('fs')
const csv =  require('csv-parser')
const fileStorageEngine = multer.memoryStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, './csv');
  }
  ,
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  },
});
const upload = multer({storage:fileStorageEngine});
app.post('/uploadcsv',upload.single("upfile"),async(req,res)=>{
const file = req.file;

const stream = Readable.from(file.buffer);

stream.pipe(csv()).on("data",(data)=>console.log(data));
res.send("file uploaded")
})
```